# word vba- how to get index value of word during find

Tags: vba, indexing, find, ms-word

Is it possible to get the word index during .find? I do .find.text to get the word, but I need its index position, then save it in an array.

normally, it is

```
    documents("doc").word(index)
```

but if i something like this:

```
    dim indexarray() as long
    dim i as long
    i = 0

    with documents("doc").content.find

         .text = word

         do while .execute
            redim preserve indexarray(i)
            indexarray(i) = index
            i = i+1
         loop

    end with
```

Is it possible to get index without loop?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get it so simply but... explain your needs by describing the idea of your project- I think I could suggest some workaround (if you want one) if I know your goal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to get number of word you selected/found but there are some possible workarounds depending on your needs. Here I'll present one idea.

I have changed some of the code you presented- see some comments inside:

```
Sub Workaround()

    Dim indexarray() As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Index
    i = 0

    'searching by Range object variable
    Dim DocRNG
    Set DocRNG = ActiveDocument.Content 'here change into your document object

    'start searching with reference to variable
    With DocRNG.Find

         .Text = "commodo"  'here your text to search

         Do While .Execute

            ReDim Preserve indexarray(i)

            'possible workaround!!!
            Index = ActiveDocument.Range(0, DocRNG.End).Words.Count

            indexarray(i) = Index
            i = i + 1
         Loop

    End With
End Sub
```

**Important!** please keep in mind that some characters like: comma, point, semicolon, etc. belong to `Words collection`, too. Therefore these sentences:

```
Nunc viverra, imperdiet enim. Fusce est; Vivamus a tellus!
```

returns 13 words while you could count 9 of them. However, proposed workaround will work correctly which I **tried and tested.**

Comment: Great, works perfectly. I needed alternative to looping, this is faster. Thanks so much.